# Reading json file line by line

Tags: python, json

I have a json file

```
{
  "rows": [
    {
     "votes": {
     "funny": 0, 
     "useful": 1, 
     "cool": 0
     }, 
     "user_id": "zvNimI98mrmhgNOOrzOiGg", 
      "review_id": "I7Kte2FwXWPCwdm7ispu1A", 
      "text": "Pretty good dinner with a nice selection of food"

      },
      {
      "votes": {
      "funny": 2, 
       "useful": 5, 
       "cool": 0
     }, 
      "user_id": "Au3Qs-AAZEWu2_4gIMwRgw", 
      "review_id": "SSlO5u2nIJ8PoAKAgN5m3Q", 
      "text": "Yeah, thats right a five freakin star rating."
    }
  ]
}
```

I just want to read the `"text"` one by one i.e. I want to access the first `"text"`, do some operation on it, and then move onto the next `"text"`.

Comment: Ok, now that we know what you want, what's the question? What part of the problem don't you understand?

Comment: Is the problem that you want to read the file into python in a specific way, or that you don't know how to use the json once you have a dict?

Answer (score 3):

It's a simple matter to open a file, read the contents as JSON, then iterate over the data you get:

```
import json
with open("my_data.json") as my_data_file:
    my_data = json.load(my_data_file)

for row in my_data["rows"]:
    do_something(row["text"])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply access the data like in a dict, since your current json data is already one:

```
>>> text = """{
  "rows": [
    {
     "votes": {
     "funny": 0, 
     "useful": 1, 
     "cool": 0
     }, 
     "user_id": "zvNimI98mrmhgNOOrzOiGg", 
      "review_id": "I7Kte2FwXWPCwdm7ispu1A", 
      "text": "Pretty good dinner with a nice selection of food"

      },
      {
      "votes": {
      "funny": 2, 
       "useful": 5, 
       "cool": 0
     }, 
      "user_id": "Au3Qs-AAZEWu2_4gIMwRgw", 
      "review_id": "SSlO5u2nIJ8PoAKAgN5m3Q", 
      "text": "Yeah, thats right a five freakin star rating."
    }
  ]
}"""
```

Assuming the above is your json text, (which can be obtained using a simple 
`with open("json_file.txt", "r") as f: text = f.read()`, you can now get convert the json into a dictionary format using

```
>>> import json
>>> json_data = json.loads(text)
```

To access the data, you can now operae normally as you would on a dict.

So, in a list comprehension, this becomes:

```
>>> print [d["text"] for d in json_data["rows"]]
['Pretty good dinner with a nice selection of food',
 'Yeah, thats right a five freakin star rating.']
```

And in a loop, this becomes

```
>>> for d in json_data["rows"]:
...     print d["text"]

Pretty good dinner with a nice selection of food
Yeah, thats right a five freakin star rating.
```

Note that the json is not read line by line, it is converted in entirety and only then the required fields are accessed.

Comment: Your example is flawed; `json` doesn't contain json data, it is a dict. While similar, it is not the same as reading json data from a file.

Comment: i just want it to return "Pretty good dinner with a nice selection of food" i.e the first text only

Comment: @dipit You said "one by one". The loop does that.

Comment: @dipit `I just want to read the "text" one by one i.e. I want to access the first "text", do some operation on it, and then move onto the next "text".` Well, I'm printing that text, and similarly you can do any operation on it within the `for` loop.

Comment: @BryanOakley Didn't get you, the json that OP is talking about is already a dict, so it can be accessed like one. As for reading them line by line, that was part of the question. Anyway, do the edits make that clear now?

Comment: No, the OP has a _file_ with text in it. It is not a python dict. It can be converted to a dict, but it is not a dict as it sits on his disk.

Comment: @BryanOakley Oh okay, got it now, have edited my answer.